# How to select -webkit-filter: drop-shadow with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I used -webkit-filter: drop-shadow on a .png transparent image to give a nice 3D effect to it. Now, I'd like to have the drop shadow change color on hover slowly using jQuery.

The css:

```
  .image { -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 2px #fff); }
```

Now I want to use jQuery to animate that drop shadow something like this:

```
 $(".image").hover(function() { 
   $(this).animate({dropShadow: "2px 2px 2px #00f"},500);
 }, function() { 
   $(this).animate({dropShadow: "2px 2px 2px #fff"},500);
 });
```

I made up "dropShadow" as an example. I've searched around, but I don't see how I can select
a webkit-filter like drop shadow. Is it even possible?

Comment: Why not use pure CSS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using pure CSS alone like below:

**HTML:**

```
<img class='image' src='path_to_your_image.format' />
```

**CSS:**

```
.image {
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-filter 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.image {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #0f0);
}
.image:hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #00f);
}
```

Or, if for some reason you really need jQuery then you can do like below. This sample essentially adds/removes a separate class with a different drop-shadow setting on `hover`.

**CSS:**

```
.image {
    -webkit-transition:-webkit-filter 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
.image {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #0f0);
}
.hover {
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(5px 5px 5px #00f);
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function () {
    $(".image").hover(function () {
        $(".image").toggleClass("hover");
    });
});
```

[**Sample with pure CSS**](http://jsfiddle.net/YHcL2/2/) | [**Sample with jQuery + CSS**](http://jsfiddle.net/YHcL2) | [**Target Filter from jQuery**](http://jsfiddle.net/YHcL2/3/)

Comment: I didn't even know I could do this with CSS alone, learned a lot from this answer, thank you